# Write Data in a JSON File

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have a form that uses AJAX and SERIALIZE to get the input. I can get the user inputs but my problem is my PHP code for writing the input to the file.

here is my JSON FILE.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "walletname": "Realtime My Salary",
        "bank": "doreming1.png",
        "icon": "generic-wallet.png",
        "currency": "US $",
        "amount": "15,935"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "walletname": "Free Wallet",
        "bank": "doreming2.png",
        "icon": "generic-wallet.png",
        "currency": "JPN \u00a5",
        "amount": "5,000"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "walletname": "Sample Wallet",
        "bank": "doreming3.png",
        "icon": "generic-wallet.png",
        "currency": "US $",
        "amount": "1,000"
    }
]
```

HERE is my PHP CODE

```
<?php

   $myFile = "js/data.json";
   $arr_data = array(); // create empty array

  try
  {

        //Get data from existing json file
       $jsondata = file_get_contents($myFile);

       // converts json data into array
       $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

       $id = count($arr_data) + 1;

       $icon = "generic-wallet.png";
       $amount = "12,000";

       //Get form data
       $formdata = array(
          'id'=>$id,
          'walletname'=> $_POST['"wallet-name'],
          'bank'=> $_POST['wallet-select-bank'],
          'icon'=>$icon,
          'currency'=> $_POST['wallet-select-currency'],
          'amount'=> $amount
        );

       // Push user data to array
       array_push($arr_data,$formdata);

       //Convert updated array to JSON
       $jsondata = json_encode($arr_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

       //write json data into data.json file
       if(file_put_contents($myFile, $jsondata)) {
             echo "ok";
        }
       else  {
            echo "not";
       }

   }
   catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
   }

?>
```

AJAX

```
                      var a = $('#add-wallet-form').serialize();
                      $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'save.php',
                        data: a,
                        beforeSend: function() {
                        myApp.alert(a);
                        },
                        success: function(response) {
                             myApp.alert('OK');
                        },
                        error: function(response) {
                             myApp.alert('Not OK');
                        }
                      });
```

It does not show any error on my browser console and also nothing happens to my existing JSON file. Even in my AJAX success and error function do not receive any response.

Comment: it really sounds like nothing at all is happening. Is the ajax call (which you haven't shown) even executing? You can see it in your browser's Network tab.

Comment: I can see this

XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/doreming-app2/save.php"

Comment: and if you click into that and view the Response tab, what does it say? Is there any data? Also what is the response code? "200 OK", or something else? And please show us how you're making the ajax call.

Comment: Hi this I Ipdate the post for ajax call and also I cannot see when  I click it

Comment: not sure what you mean you can't see? You're looking for this: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#response (that's for Chrome, but it's very similar in IE and Firefox. In some browsers you may have to enable capture of network requests before you see anything).

Comment: Also in the question you said "Even in my AJAX success and error function do not receive any response"...but you don't actually have an ajax "error" function at all. You should be supplying an option something like this `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { myApp.alert("An error occurred: " + jqXHR.status + " " + jqXHR.statusText); }`

Comment: Basically what this question boils down to is that you haven't done any debugging of your call and are just shrugging your shoulders and saying "it doesn't work" without really investigating. There's nothing obviously wrong with your code as written, so perhaps something in your environment is an issue. If you don't understand how to debug ajax calls, now would be a good time to learn. That Chrome documentation is a good way to learn about the functionality of the dev tools, plus there are tutorials about the topic available online if you search.

Comment: I put success and error functions but It returns success but my json file did not update at all

Comment: Right ok so we have some progress, we've narrowed down the problem to the PHP side. But like I said _what is the actual response from the ajax call? Look in the network tab...e.g. does it return either the word "ok", or "not" in the response body, or an exception message? All 3 are possibilities based on your code, despite the HTTP call having been successful. Like I said, you just need to do some detailed investigation and debugging. Trace what happens to your code and what paths it takes.

Comment: Thank  you for you help. I found the netwotk tab it says

save.php 200 OK

Comment: I found some systax error on my php it is now inserting but my problem is it is not following the format can you please tell me how?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Dh5ce5n

Comment: it's because you're pushing the new data into the outer object, not into the "items" array

Comment: Hi! yes I already figure it out. Thanks!! My problem now is about updating each by using the ID, is that possible with php and ajax?

Comment: sure, just look through the items array, find the entry which has the ID you want, alter it, and write the file again. But...what's the overall purpose of this functionality? Are you trying to use this JSON file as a data store? Will there be multiple users using this page? If so, then this solution will not scale at all, you'll get write access conflicts. You should use a relational database (e.g. mysql etc) to store the data, and merely use JSON as the format to transmit it between the browser and the server. That's the much more usual design, rather than literally storing JSON in a file.

Comment: Can you give some example how to edit using my adding code in PHP? I only use this for demo purpose basically I only have 5 unique ID in the JSON file.

Comment: you simply write a foreach loop which loops through the entries in `$arr_data["items"]`, each time it loops it looks at the ID property of the current entry. If it matches the ID you want to update, then modify that entry, update the array and exit the loop. The logic isn't hard and no unusual code is required, you can give it a try quite easily.